# Braintree integration with VueJS and Express server has different MerchantID on Heroku than localhost

Tags: express, heroku, vue.js, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm hosting my VueJS app on Heroku with an express server to serve the app and handle Braintree payments.

The app works pergectly on my localhost but I have a different merchant ID cropping up on my Heroku deployment that I cannot find defined anywhere in my app.

My localhost works perfectly and has correct ID but the heroku version doesn't. I'm specifying merchant ID etc. in a .env file – would that be ignored? or could it mean my web server isn't starting properly?

https://sisters-with-braces.herokuapp.com/#/

A test transaction can be run with card number 5555 5555 5555 4444 and expiry 09/20

Comment: Usually .env isn't put into your version control system. Are you sure it's set up on the server properly?

Comment: I've since defined the values in my Heroku config vars but it's still using the values from here (only in deployment, not locally) https://github.com/b2709f1b/poc-vue-landing-store

Comment: Is it possible you've cached your config values? On your Heroku server, run `php artisan config:clear` (or call artisan however you run artisan commands on Heroku)

Comment: Thanks, have tried clearing caches but no avail :(

Comment: @NathanHeffley and when Heroku runs `npm start`, it lists my (correct) information for each of the environment variables! Very confusing